# maven-site-plugin not generating apidocs folder with javadocs

Tags: maven, javadoc

I inherited a project that is supposed to build javadoc files and place them in the site directory.  This is not being done.  I have looked at all the examples I can find and I can't figure out where the configuration is broken.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>site</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.8</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bound maven site plugin's `site` goal to `prepare-package` phase.  You have configured `javadoc` generation in this plugin configuration.

As such, if you run maven's default lifecycle goals like `mvn package` or `mvn install` you should get site report with javadocs.

If you ran `mvn site`, it would skip `prepare-package` phase to which your plugin configuration is bound and hence would not generate javadoc.

Comment: The prepare-package is not skipped in case of mvn site it is simply not part of the life-cycle (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).